# Creating excel 2007 using PHPExcel

Tags: codeigniter, phpexcel

I tried to create .xlsx file in codeigniter by using PHPExcel. I have no problem when I run my aplication in windows server. but, I have an error when I run it in Linux server. This is my error message :

> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: require_once(PHPExcel/Cell.php): failed to open stream: No
>   such file or directory
>
> Filename: libraries/PHPExcel.php
>
> Line Number: 30

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is PHPExcel installed on the Linux box?  Does it have at least PHP 5.2.0?  See its [requirements](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Requirements&referringTitle=Home).

Comment: My PHP version is 5.3.14-1~dotdeb.0
What do you mean with "Linux Box" ?

Comment: I mean the Linux server.

Comment: Yes. is subdomain give an impact ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how a subdomain might be related.

Answer (score 0):

Check the capitlisation of the folders & files. Linux servers take capitalisation into account, while windows servers do not.

So if you are after "PHPExcel/Cell.php" - then the folder MUST be

```
/PHPExcel    NOT /phpexcel
```

and Cell.php MUST be with a capital C

```
Cell.php     NOT cell.php
```

Comment: there is no problem with capitalisation